# Viewing Solidworks Files

Tags: cad

Is there software available with which I can open and view Solidworks files SLDPRT, SLDASM, SLDDRW. I am a relative novice, using Ubuntu 12.04. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu users were able to install [eDrawings 2010 using wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3869) which lets you view solidworks files.

eDrawinds viewer can be downloaded for free from the [official website](http://www.edrawingsviewer.com/)

you can install wine or playonlinux with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

playonlinux is a graphical abstraction for wine with an easier configuration and installation options, it lets you install eDrawings with less hassle.

Comment: The above code will install both.  I honestly see no reason both needs to be installed.

Comment: Yes you are right Virusboy, but playonlinux already requires wine anyway (if I still remember the dependencies). It is possible to just go with playonlinux installation, that would be easier for new Ubuntu users.